# Selenium doesn't accept cookies if browser is running

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, cookies, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get cookies in selenium from my default google profile. While I'm trying to get the cookies, if the browser is closed everything goes well. But if my browser is running it can't receive cookies. And i found another bug, if i run selenium without --headless mode it raise exception `(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)`
my init of selenium looks like this

```py
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Server\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chrome_options.add_argument(
    "--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get cookies from a browser, you need to attach to the existing browser session instead of creating a new one. You can do it using the `--remote-debugging-port` option in Chrome.
I added them in the code you can try this one, hope it helps:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36")
chrome_options.add_argument(f"--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # Use the port number you specified when starting Chrome

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Is there a way not to connect to an existing browser because in my logic the browser may or may not be running or is it possible to somehow figure out where to connect?

Comment: @СерверЧауш there is not a straightforward method but you can use `browser_cookie3` library